# HDD faster than Ramdisk

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, ramdisk

I have a raid0 using 3x 1tb gen4x4 nvme m.2 drives. Bundled to drive C:

This is my **ssd speed**:

[image]

---

Then I decided to look if a ramdisk is faster. So I created a Ramdisk on drive F:

This is the **ramdisk** speed:

[image]

---

Question: Can I say that a Ramdisk is bad?

Comment: For your use case, probably. Ramdisks have a problem in that you may well bbe writing through a systemwide disk cache which buffers reads and writes through resulting in a weird RAM read/write amplification problem that isn't seen by other devices because they're reading from the device into RAM  rather than RAM copying to RAM

Comment: For bandwidths like that, not just any software will do. The ramdisk software probably has a design issue limiting performance. Perhaps try a different one.

Comment: What you're using for the ramdisk might be important here, as @DanielB pointed out

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

it is entirely possible that once you have multiple m.2 devices working together then you may be able to achieve higher bandwidth than a RAM disk.

Let's look at an [i7-9700k](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/186604/intel-core-i79700k-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz/specifications.html)

> Max Memory Bandwidth: 41.6 GB/s

Now that figure might look high, but that will be for a single direction long transfer. RAM is not full-duplex so when reading and writing in tandem you will get half of that.

In the best case that means directly reading one block of memory and writing to another will see

> Max Memory Bandwidth: 20.8 GB/s

Now you also have to take into account the operating system and program you are using. It has filesystem caches, buffers for the data being read or written. Reading from the CrystalDiskMark buffer, copying to the operating system write-through cache, and then writing at the final device is now two distinct read/write operations. That cuts down bandwidth for writing data yet again to

> Max Memory Bandwidth: 10.4 GB/s

Now it may well be that the ramdisk or crystaldiskmark is disabling the disk cache while writing and during writes the ramdisk software simply allocates a block of RAM for the program to copy into and that is why you get a higher figure there, but for reads every transaction the ramdisk software will need to do a lookup for where the data is stored, wasting precious CPU cycles and memory bandwidth.

It's hard to know exactly why the read figure is so much lower than the write for the ramdisk.

M.2 drives, and storage disks in general have some bonuses in that they are not having to use RAM to copy everything a second time.

For writes they could well see the 20.8GB/s figure, one read from the program buffer and one copy from memory to the nvme raid drive controller.

For reads they may well see the full 41.6GB/s (or as close as the PCIE bandwidth can reach) as it would simply be copying the data over PCIe into memory, the program would not be reading it to check it and the operating system simply gave the PCIE device a buffer somewhere in its disk cache and said "put your data there" with no extra copies, reads or writes needed.

The reason we used to use ramdisks in the past was because RAM bandwidth was often orders of magnitude faster than storage. The monumental difference made the halving of bandwidth a relatively small sacrifice for the times we needed the extra boost.

For the case of mechanical hardware disks RAM still is far, far faster, and the seek times of RAM compared to them is a world of difference.  Having to wait 9milliseconds before you can even read some data really does cripple random data reads from mechanical disks, while a ramdisk would have latency measured in nanoseconds which would be millions of times faster and depending on the task result in a significant boost.

NVMe and PCIe is changing that. Flash storage seek times are far lower than mechanical disks and the total bandwidth difference is in the order of a few multiples, like 4 or 8 times in some cases, rather than 10 or 100 times slower as would be with mechanical disks.

Comment: More details on my system: Gigabyte z690 UD (DDR5 Version @5200 MHz, i9 12900k)

Comment: @grim, you should add additional info to your question (EDIT).

Comment: @JoepvanSteen the question is over two years old

Comment: Ah, i sometimes miss that if these old question keep popping up. ('modified to day') - I find that feature super annoying.